# How to calculate FFT([a1, a2, . . . , an]) in time O(n), when you know FFT([a0, a1, . . . , an−1])?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

I came across this problem while studying the FFT, but I have no idea how to solve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Lookup DFT shifting theorem and think about how you can deal with the two different elements.

Comment: Alternatively, expand the DFTs of the two sequences and find out how to compute the one from the other.